# ingress controller path based routing for apache applications deployed on kubernetes

Tags: apache, kubernetes, tomcat, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a tomcat image with deployed SampleWebApp.war in conf/webapps
I am deploying this image inside pod on kubernetes cluster.

I want to expose clusterIP service pointing to tomcat application through ingress controller.
I can't use "/" in my ingress controller for redirection as already another application is using same host and path "/"

I tried giving path as "tomcat" . but it is not accessible when i tried to open UI on web

Below are my yaml's. can someone suggest what can be done here ?

```
Deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcatinfra
  namespace: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcatinfra
  template:
    metadata:
      name: tomcatinfra
      labels:
        app: tomcatinfra
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: saravak/tomcat8
        name: tomcatapp
```

```
Sevice.yaml

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tomcat-service
  namespace: tomcat
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: tomcatinfra
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 8080
```

```
Ingress :

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  namespace: tomcat
spec:
  rules:
  - host: build.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: tomcat-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /tomcat
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the annotation of ingress class

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /tomcat
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: I tried above. still can not access apache UI on http://foo.bar.com/tomcat"

Comment: Did you tried debugging logs of ingress controller ?

Comment: below are the logs in ingress controller when opening this link in UI

Comment: "GET /tomcat HTTP/1.1" 404 1080 [tomcat-tomcat-service-8080] [] 10.233.106.135:8080 1080 0.004 404

Comment: try something /tomcat/abc and see logs if it's reaching or not

Comment: no still same error in logs and UI. 404
10.233.99.0 - - [15/Nov/2022:10:04:16 +0000] "GET /tomcat/SampleWebApp  690 0.002 [tomcat-tomcat-service-8080] [] 10.233.106.135:8080 1097 0.000 404 b4f812c86ee7a062669c376ae5836075